# Prevent creation of AppWeb in provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I have a full screen provider hosted app (.NET MVC 5) with chrome control (to implement styles of the host web) which uses CSOM to make requests to the host web.

Weeks ago I thought I would need a JavaScript ClientContext, so I followed instructions to get an AppWeb created to wich I can make REST calls using RequestExecuter.

Since this change, when opening the app (via appredirect.aspx) a request parameter `SPAppWebUrl` is appended to the url.

**the problem:** If the request parameter `SPAppWebUrl` exists, the file `https://app-*****.site.com/apps/myApp/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx` is referenced, which results in a broken layout.
If I remove this parameter, it's all right.

Today I know I don't want and need the additional app web, so I removed the empty feature and Elements.xml causing its creation.

So how can I prevent creating the app web or how can I prevent the adding of SPAppWebUrl to the entry url?
I simply don't want it but cannot go back to the state before. The app web seems always be created.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

As long as a `Package\Package.package` is included in the Visual Studio project, an app web will be created.

It seems like a bug, but it was not possible to remove or delete the folder with Visual Studio.

So I deleted the `Package` folder using Windows Explorer and removed the specific lines from my .csproj file. Now the package isn't included anymore and the app will be installed without an app web.